# Rx Buffering a Fast Producing Stream with Limit + Timeout

Tags: rx-java

I'm trying to optimize web service calls with RxJava by executing batch requests when appropriate but without introducing too much delay to the response.
For that I'm using `buffer(closingSelector)` operator with `debounce()` as closing selector like this:

```java
Observable<BaseCall<T, R>> burstyMulticast = requestStream.share();
Observable<BaseCall<T, R>> burstyDeBounced = burstyMulticast.debounce(windowSize, windowUnit);
burstyMulticast.buffer(burstyDeBounced).subscribe(/* call external WS with batches */);
```

It works fine, except that if `requestStream` produces too fast it emits huge batches, too big for the WS to handle at once, so I'd like to limit the batch size somehow.
So I need a `closingSelector` that emits a close event either if there are X items in the buffer or Y amount of time passed since the last item arrived from the upstream.

I can't seem to find a good solution other than implementing a custom `Operator` which is similar to `OperatorDebounceWithTime` but with an internal buffer which returns all elements in the buffer rather than the last one.

Is there an easier way to achieve this e.g. by combining some ops?

**Edit:**

After posting the question I realised that the code piece above has another problem: if requests flowing continuously faster than debounce timeout (`requestStream` is producing faster than `windowSize`) then `burstyDeBounced` won't emit anything so all requests will be buffered until there is a long enough pause in the incoming stream.

Comment: Did you find a good solution for this problem in the end ? If so can you post it ? Cheers

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up implementing a custom op: https://gist.github.com/zsoltm/79462b37c0943b4fbef2ee3968155f27 it seems to work well. I'm happy to take suggestions for improvements.

Answer (score 0):

You could split the large buffers of the debounced source into smaller ones:

```
Observable<BaseCall<T, R>> burstyMulticast = requestStream.share();
Observable<BaseCall<T, R>> burstyDeBounced = burstyMulticast
    .debounce(windowSize, windowUnit);

burstyMulticast.buffer(burstyDeBounced)
.onBackpressureBuffer()
.concatMapIterable(list -> Lists.partition(list, windowSizeLimit))
.subscribe(...);
```

where [Lists.partition](https://github.com/google/guava/blob/master/guava/src/com/google/common/collect/Lists.java#L681) is from Google Guava.

Comment: Thank you for your input, unfortunately I've realised there is another problem with the original code piece above, so I cannot use debounce please see my edit at the original post.